# Rank selected multiple columns in a dataframe and then add rank data as new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, ranking

The example data looks like this:

```
players <- seq(1:10)
mean_K <- round(runif(10,1,10),2)
mean_D <- round(runif(10,0,10),2)
mean_A <- round(runif(10,0,10),2)
d <- cbind(players, mean_K, mean_A, mean_D)
d <- as_tibble(d)
d
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   players mean_K mean_A mean_D
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1   3.58   9.21   3.4 
 2       2   3.8    0.49   1.33
 3       3   2.47   2.29   1.72
 4       4   1.52   7.25   6.11
 5       5   8.73   3.98   8.08
 6       6   8.08   9.77   3.88
 7       7   3.97   4.52   9.93
 8       8   2.84   6.83   9.57
 9       9   3.87   0.35   5.32
10      10   2.82   3.8    3.09
```

What I want to do is rank selected columns at the same time, I tried to use **apply** :

```
apply(d[,2:4], 2, rank)
```

Output:

```
      mean_K mean_A mean_D
 [1,]      5      9      4
 [2,]      6      2      1
 [3,]      2      3      2
 [4,]      1      8      7
 [5,]     10      5      8
 [6,]      9     10      5
 [7,]      8      6     10
 [8,]      4      7      9
 [9,]      7      1      6
[10,]      3      4      3
```

But then I was stuck, how can I add all the new rank columns to the dataframe d? And I wonder if it is possible to do it using dplyr pipes %>%?

My desired output might looks like this:

```
   players mean_K mean_K_ranking mean_D mean_D_ranking mean_A mean_A_ranking
1        1   3.58              5   3.40              4   9.21              9
2        2   3.80              6   1.33              1   0.49              2
3        3   2.47              2   1.72              2   2.29              3
4        4   1.52              1   6.11              7   7.25              8
5        5   8.73             10   8.08              8   3.98              5
6        6   8.08              9   3.88              5   9.77             10
7        7   3.97              8   9.93             10   4.52              6
8        8   2.84              4   9.57              9   6.83              7
9        9   3.87              7   5.32              6   0.35              1
10      10   2.82              3   3.09              3   3.80              4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign. Here, we used `lapply` to loop over the columns (in case there are some difference in `type`, then `lapply` preserves it while `apply` converts to `matrix` and there would be a single type for those)

```
lst1 <- lapply(d[2:4], rank)
d[paste0(names(lst1), "_ranking")] <- lst1
```

---

Or using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/)

```
library(dplyr)
d <- d %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('mean'), rank, .names = "{.col}_ranking"))
```

---

Or can use `imap` from `purrr` to order the columns as in the expected

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
d %>% 
    select(starts_with('mean_')) %>% 
    imap_dfc(~ tibble(!! .y := .x, 
        !!str_c(.y, '_ranking') := rank(.x))) %>% 
    bind_cols(d %>% 
               select(players), .)
```

Comment: wow, thank you! dplyr::across is actually what I am looking for!